# RetroPie + Ultracabs USB 2 player interface

Tags: retropie, gamepad

I have running on my Raspberry 3 RetroPie 4.0-rc1.

There are many nice tutorials to when it comes to install it and setup the roms even just a few cover the most important thing: the gamepads!

Each one of them has its own way to be installed or maybe it comes already with the compatible interface.

I am lucky and in my case, I have a generic 2 player pad that the [Ultracabs](http://www.ultracabs.co.uk/arcade-usb-interface-71-p.asp) USB interface gives me.

The problem is that being a 2 player device, just one gamepad is detected. So just one player gets configured.

What can I do in this case? What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Many lines have been written about this problem in the [retropie forum](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/search/ultracabs?in=titlesposts).

My actual solution was to just add to the /boot/cmdline.txt the bold text to the actual input:

> **usbhid.quirks=0x16c0:0x05e1:0x040** dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet loglevel=3 consoleblank=0